# If the mind is spatial does that mean it is material and cannot contain qualia?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, dualism

The reason that people like mind body dualism is that material things cannot contain qualia and therefore there must be another entity that explains our consciousness.

However, if we assume that the mind is a spatial entity, wouldn't that mean that it cannot account for qualia because this would make it make it material?

Comment: There is no relation between material, spatial, and having qualia, any combination of yes/no on all three is possible. [Property dualists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_dualism#Panpsychist_property_dualism) have spatial, material minds with qualia in them.

Comment: confusing question!

Answer (score 1):

Phrase "mind is spatial" should not be understood as mind exists in space, but more of space exists in mind. This of course comes mostly from [Kant and his transcendental aesthetics](http://www.generation-online.org/p/fpkanttranscendentalaesthetics.htm). According to him, space (and time) are properties of the mind, every sensation mind perceives must be in space and in time (spatial and temporal). Consequently, qualia, as mostly sensory experience is also spatial and temporal.

There is also another explanation of qualia, more scientific and simpler to understand. Certain qualia like for example seeing red color is encoded in our brain (pattern in the neurons). We do not know how this particular pattern is encoded, so we cannot transfer it to another being. But as neuroscience progresses, it would be able to codify and reproduce this pattern, therefore theoretically able to reproduce qualia of one person in another persons brain (mind) .